# how to insert checkbox values especially image url to mysql using jsp

Tags: jsp

how to insert checkbox values especially image url to mysql using jsp

Comment: way too vague. how do you access your database, which framework do you use, etc.?

Answer (score 1):

Give all checkboxes the same `name` but a different `value`.

```
<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" value="foo">
<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" value="bar">
<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" value="baz">
```

Then you can obtain them in the servlet using [`HttpServletRequest#getParameterValues()`](http://java.sun.com/javaee/5/docs/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#getParameterValues%28java.lang.String%29).

```
String[] checked = request.getParameterValues("checkbox");
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to connect to the database, either directly via JDBC or via an ORM like Hibernate.

Then you simply issue a query or create an persist an object which stores your data.